# I have two login pages for two type of users whenever I click remember me fields are kept in both login pages

Tags: java, android

I am developing an application(my graduation project) for two types of users, in the login page there is a checkbox to remember credentials of a user, however when it is checked the credentials are shown in both login pages
I am using SharedPreferences

Code snippet from login as restaurant:

```
public class LoginAsRestaurant extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    EditText lRestName;
    EditText lRestPass;
    CheckBox saveLoginCheckBox;
    private SharedPreferences loginAsRestPreferences;
    private Boolean saveLogin;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor loginPrefsEditor;
    String username, password;

//__________________onCreate Method________________//
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.loginasrestaurant);
       //refer to views
       lRestName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.RestUsername);
        lRestPass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.RestPassword);
        final Button loginAsRest = (Button)findViewById(R.id.loginAsRestaurant);
        saveLoginCheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.RestRememberCust);
        loginAsRestPreferences = getSharedPreferences("loginPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
        loginPrefsEditor = loginAsRestPreferences.edit();
        /////////////////////////////Rememberme/////////////////////////////////////////////
        saveLogin = loginAsRestPreferences.getBoolean("saveLogin", false);
        if (saveLogin == true) {

            lRestName.setText(loginAsRestPreferences.getString("username", ""));
            lRestPass.setText(loginAsRestPreferences.getString("password", ""));
            saveLoginCheckBox.setChecked(true);
        }
}//end of onCreate method
//_________________________________________________________________________//
       public void onClick(View v){
  if (saveLoginCheckBox.isChecked()) {
            loginPrefsEditor.putBoolean("saveLogin", true);
            loginPrefsEditor.putString("username", username);
            loginPrefsEditor.putString("password", password);
            loginPrefsEditor.commit();
        } else {
            loginPrefsEditor.clear();
            loginPrefsEditor.commit();
        }
}//end of onClick method

}//end of class
```

This is the code snippet from login as customer:

```
public class LoginAsCustomer extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    // //////////////////////Widgets in Login Tab//////////////////////////////
    EditText lCustUserName;
    EditText lCustPassword;
    CheckBox saveLoginCheckBox;
    private SharedPreferences loginPreferences;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor loginPrefsEditor;
    private Boolean saveLogin;




    String username, password;
//_______________________________________________________//
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.loginascustomer);
  ///////////////////////// Widgets definition (Login Tab)/////////////
        lCustUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.CustUsername);
        lCustPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.CustPassword);
        final Button loginAsCustomer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginAsCustomer);
        saveLoginCheckBox = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.RememberCust);
        loginPreferences = getSharedPreferences("loginPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
        loginPrefsEditor = loginPreferences.edit();

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        saveLogin = loginPreferences.getBoolean("saveLogin", false);
        if (saveLogin == true) {

            lCustUserName.setText(loginPreferences.getString("username", ""));
            lCustPassword.setText(loginPreferences.getString("password", ""));
            saveLoginCheckBox.setChecked(true);}
}//end of onCreate method
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (saveLoginCheckBox.isChecked()) {
            loginPrefsEditor.putBoolean("saveLogin", true);
            loginPrefsEditor.putString("username", username);
            loginPrefsEditor.putString("password", password);
            loginPrefsEditor.commit();
        } else {
            loginPrefsEditor.clear();
            loginPrefsEditor.commit();
        }
}//end of onClick method
}end of class
```

Comment: Question not clear. What is your objective?

Comment: The application has two login pages: one for customers and other for restaurant, each of the login pages has remember me checkbox, when I  want to login as customer and save my credentials so I don't have to enter them every time I use , I click on the checkbox(true) it is supposed to show credentials only in customer login page, but it is showing in both customer and restaurant , and vice versa when I login as restaurants, hope this is more specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because both class have same Preferences name "saveLogin". Use unique name like this,

In LoginAsRestaurant class

```
saveLogin = loginPreferences.getBoolean("customerLogin", false);
```

In LoginAsCustomer class

```
saveLogin = loginPreferences.getBoolean("restaurentLogin", false);
```